# Profile not found 404 error when attempting to store app credentials using "ionic security" command

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the new Ionic Package facility to build an ios app.

I have been through the process of creating the ios certificate and provisioning profile. I'm now trying to add those to my ionic project using the ionic security command in the ionic CLI.

I have followed the sample command [from the docs](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/security-profiles):

```
ionic security credentials ios --profile my_first_profile -c ~/Downloads/Certificate.p12 -p my_certificate_password -r ~/Downloads/MyProfile.mobileprovision
```

(but obviously replaced profileId, certificate location and provisioning profile location with my own parameters.)

When I run the command I get a 404: requested URL was not found error (I have redacted my request_id):

```
Body: {"error":{"title":"404: Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.","type":"NotFound","details":"Profile not found.","link":null},"meta":{"request_id":"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx","version":"1.0.0-alpha","status":404}}
```

Is this something I'm doing wrong or a problem on the Ionic server? What can I do to fix it?

Many thanks